# Keep getting exception in python webserver

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

I have a pretty simple python webserver that returns a few web pages, and it keeps throwing `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`. Here is my code, can anyone tell what is wrong?

```
from os import curdir
from os.path import join as pjoin
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/store.json":
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'store.json')) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/json')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read())
        elif self.path == "/Stock.htm":
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'stock.htm')) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read())
        else:
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'index.htm')) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read())
    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/store.json':
            length = self.headers.getheader('content-length')
            data = self.rfile.read(int(length))
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'store.json'), 'w') as fh:
                fh.write(data)
            self.send_response(200)

server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), StoreHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Here is the exception output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2012 16:48:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 58645)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 306, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 332, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 345, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 666, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 400, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 388, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "C:\Users\Arlen\Desktop\Stock Recorder\webserver.py", line 25, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write(fh.read())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 317, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
----------------------------------------
```

**Update:** Here is how my updated code looks:

```
from os import curdir
from os.path import join as pjoin

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/store.json":
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'store.json')) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/json')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read(), 'rb')
        elif self.path == "/Stock.htm":
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'stock.htm')) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read(), 'rb')
        else:
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'index.htm')) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read(),'rb')
    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/store.json':
            length = self.headers.getheader('content-length')
            data = self.rfile.read(int(length))
            with open(pjoin(curdir, 'store.json'), 'w') as fh:
                fh.write(data)
            self.send_response(200)

server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), StoreHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets send and receive bytes, but you are attempting to send over unicode strings since you opened the file without specifying the mode (remember, in Python 3 all strings are unicode by default).

You can either:

- Use the [`bytes` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) to transform the data

*- or -*

- Open the file in binary mode - change `open(pjoin(curdir, 'a.file'))` to `open(pjoin(curdir, 'store.json'), 'rb')` (note the additional `rb` parameter).

Comment: It says `TypeError: write() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: @ArlenBeiler - it should be your `with open` calls that have the `, 'rb'` added to them - the `write` calls won't know what to do with it (read my answer again) ;-)