# Python webserver does not return success when recieving post

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple python webserver that saves a `POST` to a file, but for some reason chrome tells me that it didn't work right. However, the file does get updated, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Here is the offending code:

```
def do_POST(self):
    if self.path == '/store.json':
        length = self.headers['content-length']
        data = self.rfile.read(int(length))
        with open(pjoin(curdir, 'store.json'), 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(data)
        self.send_response(200)
```

If you want to look at my entire code, I have it in another question: [Keep getting exception in python webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13147405/258482) I fixed a few things since that question, but that is basically how it looks.

Comment: well, you don't actually return anything in http response. could this be an issue?

Comment: I don't know. What should I send?

Comment: Arlen: a [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) might be a good idea.